# Proper settings file creation for Windows 7, Vista and XP

Tags: .net, windows-7, filesystems

After installing one of my .Net apps on a Windows 7 machine I keep getting an error that my application does not have permission to save a settings file to the application folder under the program files folder. I'm aware it's possible to elevate to administrator privileges or whatever but I'd like to avoid this. I know Windows 7 and Vista have a particular location where they would like you to save settings files but I'm unsure of how to determine this location in .Net. Could anyone offer some assistance or suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to return the various 'special' directories on the user's system. You can use these as the parameters to the [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx) method.

Comment: The `enum` itself doesn't give you a path.

Comment: Thanks, I explicitly added the method to call :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you! +1s all around!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`Environment.GetFolderPath` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx), and its `ApplicationData` parameter.